# How to query months and number of days in a month of current year in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a table of 2 columns and 12 rows as a result of MySQL/SQL query:

1. First column is 12 months of the current year.
2. Second column is the number of days in each month.

Table should look similar to:

- **months**    **days**
- January     31
- February    28
- ...        ...
- December    31

I tried:

```
DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_loop$$
 CREATE PROCEDURE my_loop()
 BEGIN
 DECLARE x INT;

 SET x = 1;

 WHILE x  <= 12 DO
 SELECT monthname(SUBDATE("2019-12-01", INTERVAL x month)) as months, day(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE("2019-12-01", INTERVAL x month))) as days;
 SET  x = x + 1; 
 END WHILE;

 END$$
DELIMITER ;

call my_loop();
```

But it prints out only the first iteration:

- months days
- January 31

How can I solve this with or without an iteration?

Comment: Your procedure is working fine, it's just returning 12 result sets. You need to deal with that in your application, or change the procedure to save the intermediate results into a temporary table and then SELECT everything from the temporary table once the loop completes. Note that you should be counting x from 11 down to 0 if you want the months in order from January to December. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Z7EkN2UtX2R2eBJWQ5mHM/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a query:

```
select monthname(makedate(year(curdate()), 1) + interval (x.mon - 1) month) as month_name,
       day(last_day(makedate(year(curdate()), 1) + interval (x.mon - 1) month)) as days_in_month
from (select 1 as mon union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
      select 5 as mon union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all
      select 9 as mon union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12 
      ) x
order by x.mon;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c85024b3bd09e6c86015a21f6b5034e7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! I like this answer. This is what I was looking for actually. But would you be able to explain some of the code in more details. E.g. I don't understand code `from (select 1 ... select 12) x`. As I understand it make a table result, but don't know how.

Comment: @Islam . . . That creates a derived table with 12 rows.