# Populate an array with 12 months of data using db results or default values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, default-value

I have a Mysql query that fetch monthly records from DB to use to draw a graph. If there is no enough data to cover the whole year (12 months) the graph will be drawn with only 2 months. This means I need to create an array that can initialize all months with '**income**' zero values. Then replace the '**income**' values with values from DB.

```
$year = date('Y');
for ($i = 1; $i < 13 ; $i++) { 
  $month = date('M-Y', strtotime('01-'.$i.'-'.$year));
  $income = 0;
  $months[] = array('dates' =>$month, 'income'=>$income);
}
print_r($months);
/*Output Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Jan-2022
            [income] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Feb-2022
            [income] => 0
        )
      etc.. etc.. up to Dec-2022
*/
```

From Db this is my result. Because the data is only 1 and 1/2 months old.

```
/*DBOutput
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Sep-2022
            [income] => 1864
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Oct-2022
            [income] => 548
        )

)*/
```

See my below code. It seems to replace **Sep-2022** '**income**' with 0, Though **Oct-2022** has correct '**income**' output.

```
foreach ($months as $key) {
        foreach ($dbdata as $db) {
          if ($key['dates'] === $db['dates']) {
            $net = $db['income'];
            $dates = $db['dates'];
          } 
          else{
            $net = $key['income'];
            $dates = $key['dates'];
          }
        }
        $graphData[] = array('dates' => $dates, 'income' => $net);
      }
      if ($graphData) {
        echo json_encode($graphData);
      }

/*Output 
[{"dates":"Jan-2022","income":0},{"dates":"Feb-2022","income":0},{"dates":"Mar-2022","income":0},{"dates":"Apr-2022","income":0},{"dates":"May-2022","income":0},{"dates":"Jun-2022","income":0},{"dates":"Jul-2022","income":0},{"dates":"Aug-2022","income":0},{"dates":"Sep-2022","income":0},{"dates":"Oct-2022","income":548},{"dates":"Nov-2022","income":0},{"dates":"Dec-2022","income":0}]
*/
```

As you can see, September's income is not getting the DB Value. I am pretty sure this code will only push the last income value in the dbArray, which is incorrect.

Comment: I do not see the reason for to perform this everything by this long and complex way. Simply generate a calendar rowset with all 12 months in a query (may even use static subquery) and set needed value if rows for this month are present and zero otherwize. Then use this output directly.

Comment: Create your $months array with the "month" as key - `$months[$month] = ...` Then you don't need to loop over it to find the matching element. You just loop over your query result, and assign `$month[$db['dates']]['income'] = $db['income'];` - no checking of any additional conditions, just stick the right value into the right place directly. Use `array_values` on the resulting array afterwards, to "reset" the keys to a normal, zero-based numeric index.

Comment: @Akina, please explain or sample code if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine and in the right logic.
You only need to replace the 'income' values with values from DB.
Do it like this:

```
foreach ($dbdata as $db) {
  // first find the key of the element
  $key = array_search($db['dates'], array_column($months, 'dates'));
  if($key !== false)){
    $months[$key]['income'] = $db['income'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, code works like a charm. Just fixed the unmatched () on if.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `array_column()` and `array_search()` on each iteration is NOT an efficient approach.

Convert your database result set into a lookup array by declaring first-level associative keys to each row based on the `dates` values.

Then when you are building your monthly rows, check the lookup array and fallback to default values when a month is not represented in the database.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Gc7qT))

```
$db = [
    ['dates' => 'Sep-2022', 'income' => 1864],
    ['dates' => 'Oct-2022', 'income' => 548]
];
$lookup = array_column($db, null, 'dates');

$year = date('Y');
for ($i = 1; $i < 13 ; ++$i) { 
    $date = date('M-Y', strtotime("$year-$i-01"));
    $months[] = $lookup[$date]
        ?? ['dates' => $date, 'income' => 0];
}
var_export($months);
```

---

That said, if this was my application, I'd probably just JOIN on a derived table that prepopulates all months in a give year with the default values so that all of the data preparation is done in the SQL query.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57459688/2943403) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61593791/2943403).